# Compare DateTime field in Mongo DB with given Date using Criteria in Kotlin Springboot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, criteria

I have a requirement where in I need to filter records in mongo db using provided referenceDate.
dateTimeValidUntil is stored as LocalDateTime in db.
Data in Db:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62c4648ba657881284cd84e0"
  },
  "college": {
    "_id": 9004,
    "name": "ZAF"
  },
  "dateTimeValidFrom": "2011-11-21T00:00:00",
  "dateTimeValidUntil": "2022-12-29T23:59:59.999999"
```

My query :

```
fun find(collegeId: Int, refDate: LocalDate): List<College> { 
return mongoTemplate.find(
            Query.query(
                Criteria.where("college._id").`is`(collegeId)
                    .andOperator(
                        Criteria().orOperator(
                            Criteria.where("dateTimeValidUntil").`is`(null),
                            Criteria.where("dateTimeValidUntil").gte(refDate)
                        )
                    )
            ),College::class.java,"college"    
        )}
```

But its not filtering out record which are ending on previous date, e.g when  refDate = 2023-01-01.
I tried to pass `refDate.atStartOfDay()` as well still its not filtering

Comment: Is `dateTimeValidUntil` date object or string? A common source of errors is that dates are improperly stored as strings and used in date comparisons.

Comment: Its a LocalDateTime

Comment: Type `LocalDateTime` does not exist in MongoDB, see [BSON Types](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/) - the question remains.

Comment: In my data class its LocalDateTime but yes it seems its saving as String

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. a Bean defining some convertors:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions

    fun customConversions(): MongoCustomConversions {
        return MongoCustomConversions(
            listOf(
                LocalDateTimeToDateConverter(),
                DateToLocalDateTimeConverter(),
                DBObjectToRULIDConverter(),
                RULIDToDBObjectConverter(),
            )
        )
    }
```

2. the convertors, picking a Timezone that's appropriate for you

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
import org.springframework.data.convert.ReadingConverter
import org.springframework.data.convert.WritingConverter
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneOffset
import java.util.*

@ReadingConverter
class DateToLocalDateTimeConverter : Converter<Date, LocalDateTime?> {
    override fun convert(source: Date): LocalDateTime? {
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(source.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC)
    }
}

@WritingConverter
class LocalDateTimeToDateConverter : Converter<LocalDateTime, Date?> {
    override fun convert(source: LocalDateTime): Date? {
        return Date.from(source.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant())
    }
}
```